# Draw Slightly Transparent Blue Rectangle in Native Win32 GDI

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

**How do I draw a blue rectangle with a alpha/transparency value of 0.5 (ie, 50% transparency) in Native Win32 C++?**

Using a macro like RGBA() fails, I'm not sure how I can specify the alpha value of the brush.

```
SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGBA(255,255,0,127));
SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGBA(255,255,0,127));
Rectangle(hdc, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the AlphaBlend function -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183351(v=vs.85).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/286/Using-the-AlphaBlend-function

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure you'll need [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do it like that, but it should be there with GDI:

```
//in rendering function
using namespace Gdiplus;
Graphics g (hdc);
SolidBrush brush (Color (127 /*A*/, 0 /*R*/, 0 /*G*/, 255 /*B*/));
g.FillRectangle (&brush, 0, 0, width, height);
```

On the plus side, GDI+, although not quite as fast, has greater capabilities and visual results, and is object-oriented, which also means you don't need to worry about all those `SelectObject` and `DeleteObject` calls.

Be aware that there are a couple of [extra steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when initializing/ending the program in order to use GDI+, and that everything is in the `Gdiplus` namespace, and `-lgdiplus`.

If you really need GDI, the only solution I know of is [AlphaBlend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which really is a more complex method than simply drawing shapes to the device context. It's always good to get started with GDI+, as it's still in use, and is much easier to use than GDI.

Comment: I don't think GDI+ Isn't faster than GDI is it? GDI is hardware accelerated but not so for GDI+ (from what I have read).

Comment: @SethCarnegie, I haven't read too much into it, but I remembered it being faster. Looking at it, you seem to be right. GDI+ still has more capability, and produces better images, though. If you're truly worried about speed (and quality at the same time), DirectX is an extremely good candidate.

Comment: Yes, there is no doubt GDI+ produces better images and has more capability. +1.

Comment: For sure GDI+ is slower than GDI (at least where you can achieve the same results). I did some measurements and it's absolutely evident.